# Pagination should not be rendered in every view in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 components 1)Content 2)Pagination

When I click on view stats button (see in screenshot) `rendermatchinfo()` method gets called and it shows details of single match and also shows pagination which should not be shown. Pagination must be shown only on home page where content component renders match details of all matches and not single match.

content.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Matchinfo from './matchinfo';
import './content.css';

class Content extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            matches:[],
            loading:true,
      callmatchinfo: false,
        matchid:''
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        fetch('api/matches')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
      console.log(res)
      this.setState({
        matches:res,
        loading:false
      });
    })
    }

  viewstats(matchid){
    this.setState({
        callmatchinfo: true,
        matchid: matchid
    });
  }

  rendermatchinfo(){
    return <Matchinfo matchid={this.state.matchid} />
  }

    renderMatches() {
        return this.state.matches.slice(this.props.start, this.props.end).map(match => {
            return (
                <div className="col-lg-3">
                    <div id="content">
                        <p className="match">MATCH {match.id}</p>
                        <h4>{match.team1}</h4>
                        <p>VS</p>
                        <h4>{match.team2}</h4>
                        <div className="winner">
                            <h3>WINNER</h3>
                            <h4>{match.winner}</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div className="stats">
                            <button type="button" onClick= {()=>{this.viewstats(match.id)}} className="btn btn-success">View Stats</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        })
    }

    render() {

        if (this.state.loading) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>
      }
      else if(this.state.callmatchinfo){
        return <Matchinfo match_id={this.state.matchid} />
    }

    return (
      <div>
          <div className="row">
            {this.renderMatches()}
              </div>
          <div className="row">
            {this.state.callmatchinfo ? this.rendermatchinfo() : ''}
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Content;
```

pagination.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Pagination extends Component {

    handleClick(val){
    this.setState({
        end:val*16,
        start:end-16
    });
    const end = val*16;
    this.props.onChange(end - 16, end);
    }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="container">                 
              <ul className="pagination">
                <li><a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 1)}>1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 2)}>2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 3)}>3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 4)}>4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 5)}>5</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Pagination;
```

Pagination and content component are imported in layout component.

layout.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Pagination from './pagination';
import Content from './content';

class Layout extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        start:0,
        end:16,

        };
    }

    onChangePagination = (start, end) => {
        this.setState({
          start,
          end
        });
    };



    render() {

    const {start, end} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
          <Content start={start} end={end}/>
          <Pagination onChange={this.onChangePagination}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Layout;
```

Screenshot:

Home page which shows pagination :

[image]

When I click on view stats button of any particular match it still shows pagination but it should not show it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move `Pagination` to `Content` component

**Layout.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Content from './content';

class Layout extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Content />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Layout;
```

**Content.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Matchinfo from './matchinfo';
import './content.css';
import Pagination from './pagination';


class Content extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            matches: [],
            loading: true,
            callmatchinfo: false,
            matchid: '',
            start: 0,
            end: 16,
        };
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('api/matches')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
                this.setState({
                    matches: res,
                    loading: false
                });
            })
    }

    onChangePagination = (start, end) => {
        this.setState({
            start,
            end
        });
    };

    viewstats(matchid) {
        this.setState({
            callmatchinfo: true,
            matchid: matchid
        });
    }

    rendermatchinfo() {
        return <Matchinfo matchid={this.state.matchid} />
    }

    renderMatches() {
        return this.state.matches.slice(this.state.start, this.state.end).map(match => {
            return (
                <div className="col-lg-3">
                    <div id="content">
                        <p className="match">MATCH {match.id}</p>
                        <h4>{match.team1}</h4>
                        <p>VS</p>
                        <h4>{match.team2}</h4>
                        <div className="winner">
                            <h3>WINNER</h3>
                            <h4>{match.winner}</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div className="stats">
                            <button type="button" onClick={() => { this.viewstats(match.id) }} className="btn btn-success">View Stats</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        })
    }

    render() {

        if (this.state.loading) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>
        }
        else if (this.state.callmatchinfo) {
            return <Matchinfo match_id={this.state.matchid} />
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="row">
                    {this.renderMatches()}
                    {!this.state.callmatchinfo && <Pagination onChange={this.onChangePagination} />}
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    {this.state.callmatchinfo ? this.rendermatchinfo() : ''}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Content;
```

Comment: I tried to make changes as mentioned by you in your answer but it does not work it `Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`

Comment: I suggest to checkout `redux ` will be much useful for your app

Comment: but I am just slicing JSON response and displaying it on each page like page 1 displays JSON objects from 1-16, page 2 -> 17-33 and so on nothing else.

Comment: I could not get what exactly happened now page that is displayed is wierd why so ? https://imgur.com/a/PBxBC

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164287/discussion-between-ali-and-stone-rock).

Comment: In simple terms I just don't want to display pagination when I click on view stats button and on home page it should display pagination.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove Pagination component from Layout component. Content component can be renamed as Matches component. Within the Matches component, show the Pagination component.

When view stat is clicked, show the MatchInfo component and hide the Matches and Pagination component.

Comment: I am passing props from layout component to pagination and content component. pagination and content are child components of layout component.

Comment: I made necessary changes please see my answer but I it is not working any edits please suggest.